# String from Activity1 in Youtube player in Activity2

Tags: java, string, youtube, youtube-api

In the youtube api you are given the following code

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo("C0DPdy98e4c"); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0DPdy98e4c
    }
}
```

Since I want to make alot of links to youtube, I don't want a layout for each youtube video. I tried to make a string in Activity1 that should transfer the youtube videolink to Activiy2.

Activity1 sending to Activity2

```
private void button_les1Click()
{
    startActivity(new Intent("company.app.activity2"));
}

public void onClick(View v) {


    Intent videoId = new Intent(this, les_video.class);
    videoId.putExtra("C0DPdy98e4c", videoId); //Input Youtube link here


    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button_les1:
            button_les1Click();
            break;
    }

    startActivity(videoId);
    finish();
}
```

This is the part that is not working, it cannot detect the string value

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    String videolink = getIntent().getExtras().getString("videoId");

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity2);

    youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youTubeView.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.loadVideo(videolink); // Play link from videolink string
    }
}
```

You probably noticed that i'm still learning this awesome language, since I think it's just a problem that i don't now how to use the string. Could somebody point out why the string isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing `putExtra.` `putExtra` works with a key-value pair. The key is a String which acts as an identifier or index for the value. The value can be a `String, int, boolean, etc.`

The keys should be stored either in XML or as constants somewhere within your application.

**In other words, it should be something like:**

```
public static final String KEY_VIDEO_LINK = "video_link";

//...

videoId.putExtra(KEY_VIDEO_LINK, "C0DPdy98e4c"); //assuming C0DPdy98e4c is the
//String that you want to send to the next Activity.
```

**And in Activity2, read it using the constant as the key:**

```
String videoLink = getIntent().getExtras().getString(Activity1.KEY_VIDEO_LINK);
```